# How PHP treats White Spaces

Tags: php

I would like to know how php treats white spaces. Reducing a white spaces in my php coding

- will reduce the page loading time ?
- Will reduce empty spaces in my view source ?
- Will reduce my program compiling time ?

Example of my code

```
<?php 
include('head.php');
-- Here is white space --
include('body.php');
-- Here is white space --
include('footer.php');
?>
```

inside body.php

```
<?php 

echo $lhs = '<div class="lhs">my content</div>';



   white

   spaces..


echo $main = '<div class="main">my content</div>';

   white

   spaces..


echo $footer ='<div class="footer">my content </div>';

?>
```

My live Coding Part

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<?php include(ROOT.'head.php'); ?>
<body>  
<div id="container">        
    <?php
    // header items => logo , searchbar , compare , myaccount/login
    include(ROOT.'headeritems.php');
    //WEBSITE MENUS
    include(ROOT.'sitemenus.php');    
    if ($page!="index"){ include(ROOT.'otherpagenotification.php'); }
    ?>        
        <div id="breadO" <?php echo ($page!="index")? 'class="bannerShd2"' :''; ?> >
        <div id="bread">
            <?php include(BREADCRUMBS); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

HTML View Source

```
1.
2.
3.       
4.    
5.  <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
6.  <html>
7.  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Samsung Galaxy Note 3</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="name" />

<meta name="rating" content="General" />
```

line number 1 to 4 is the white space like this many are in my view source

Comment: Removing white space from PHP source will make no measurable difference to anything, except possible the readability of the code.

Comment: I don't think white spaces have much to do about performance .. however they can increase the readability and file size ..

Comment: Understand that the contents of a PHP script are not downloaded by the client - just the output.

Comment: when i see view source of my page i found many white spaces then i reduced unnecessary spaces in php especially when i echo the results if the result is empty it has white space . that made many white space in view source.

Comment: Show reproducible code example.

Comment: @sectus Do u want me to show view source code along with php

Comment: @sectus i added my reproducible code

Comment: @Raaga, it's not whitespace. It's end of line. After '?>' before '<!' you have end of line which shows on result page.

Comment: @sectus how to reduce that spaces

Comment: Remove end of file symbol. For example '?><!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually inside the PHP script white there is no problem, in case if you use white space before and after php script which means

```
-------Space-----
<?php

?>

-----Space ---
```

will make an error called Header Problems. You will get an error like follwing

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23
```

Try to avoid white space like

```
1.
2.
3.       
4.    
5.  <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
6.  <html>
7.  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Samsung Galaxy Note 3</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="name" />

<meta name="rating" content="General" />
```

For more details please check the following link:
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP **ignores** white spaces. The White spaces in your page source is not from your `php` file.You are missing out of some thing

FYI

```
<html>



<?php
echo 1;
/*

These white space will be ignored by php , It won't affect your HTML code



*/
echo 2;
?>



<!-- But this white spaces above or below PHP tag will be reflected in HTML source code -->


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Will reduce the page loading time ?**
A: No

**Q: Will reduce empty spaces in my view source ?**
A: No

**Q: Will reduce my program compiling time ?**
A: No

Answer (score 0):

```
This Is Space After Calling Html Code File.
Like Inside Function.php Or Our Custome Function File Included(widget File, Meta Box File.etc BackEnd File) Space.
Please Remove Between Two Function Space Like As
WRONG :
<?php
function 1....
?>
[consider As A HTML Space]---------Remove This Part 
<?php
function 2....
?> 
Right :
<?php
function 1....

function 2....
?> No Break Between Two Function

<?php
Code ....
?>
End Check Last Of File Remove Extra Spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of things to consider. If the white spaces consern you or result in errors you should write your sameple code like:

```php
<?php

include('config.php');

?><!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html><?php

include(ROOT.'head.php');

?><body>  
<div id="container"><?php

    // header items => logo , searchbar , compare , myaccount/login
    include(ROOT.'headeritems.php');
    //WEBSITE MENUS
    include(ROOT.'sitemenus.php');    
    if ($page!="index"){ include(ROOT.'otherpagenotification.php'); }

    ?><div id="breadO" <?php echo ($page!="index")? 'class="bannerShd2"' :''; ?> >
        <div id="bread"><?php include(BREADCRUMBS); ?></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm exagerating a bit here and the result is not so readable but that would be it: line breaks inside a php block are not send to the browser everything else is.

## Use shorthand for mere output

If the only thing a PHP block does consider the shorthand `<?=...?>` like:

```
<h1><?=$title?></h1> or
<h1><?= $title ?></h1>
```

It will make reading to code so much easier on the (programmer's) eyes.

## Ommit trailing close tags

But more importantly: make it a habit **to ommit a trailing `?>`** if no html code is appearing after that!. There is no need for a trailing `?>` at the end of a php document (or class file or include file) as the PHP interpreter will very well be able to read and interpret a EOF token. Not doing so will send needless empty lines to the browser.